# Checking if points are inside of polygons

Tags: python, lambda, polygon, geojson, geopandas

I have two datasets in geoJSON format. Using geoPandas, on the one hand I have a dataset with coordinates of various points in a certain city.

**Table gdf:**

```
╔═══╦════════╦══════════╦══════════════════════╦═════════╦══════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║   ║ id     ║ layer_id ║ title                ║ lon     ║ lat      ║ geometry                 ║
╠═══╬════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ 0 ║ 83969  ║ 12       ║ Garces               ║ 2.15351 ║ 41.37926 ║ POINT (2.15351 41.37926) ║
╠═══╬════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 86258  ║ 146      ║ Ritsch               ║ 2.16235 ║ 41.38429 ║ POINT (2.16235 41.38429) ║
╠═══╬════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ 2 ║ 83964  ║ 40       ║ Lunch & Catering Bar ║ 2.15368 ║ 41.37913 ║ POINT (2.15368 41.37913) ║
╠═══╬════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ 3 ║ 83970  ║ 8        ║ Galaxia              ║ 2.15343 ║ 41.37932 ║ POINT (2.15343 41.37932) ║
╠═══╬════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ 4 ║ 74866  ║ 40       ║ Celler de l`Abi      ║ 2.14207 ║ 41.3694  ║ POINT (2.14207 41.36941) ║
╚═══╩════════╩══════════╩══════════════════════╩═════════╩══════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

On the other hand, I have another dataset where the polygons of different areas are located in the same city.

**Table polys:**

```
╔═══╦═══════╦═════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║   ║ Name  ║ ... ║ geometry                                          ║
╠═══╬═══════╬═════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 0 ║ aoi_1 ║ ... ║ POLYGON Z ((2.13049 41.38221 0.00000, 2.13101 ... ║
╠═══╬═══════╬═════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ aoi_2 ║ ... ║ POLYGON Z ((2.14463 41.39321 0.00000, 2.14495 ... ║
╠═══╬═══════╬═════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 2 ║ aoi_3 ║ ... ║ POLYGON Z ((2.14592 41.39374 0.00000, 2.14613 ... ║
╠═══╬═══════╬═════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 3 ║ aoi_4 ║ ... ║ POLYGON Z ((2.14860 41.39433 0.00000, 2.14884 ... ║
╠═══╬═══════╬═════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 4 ║ aoi_5 ║ ... ║ POLYGON Z ((2.14845 41.39443 0.00000, 2.14873 ... ║
╚═══╩═══════╩═════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

What I want to do is determine what points lie within each of the polygons and generate a new dataset. I would also like to know the most optimal way to do it because, I have around 100 polygons and around 100K points to verify in the polygons.

Using`Shapely` and property `contains`, what I am trying to do is the following::

```
inside = gdf[gdf.apply(lambda row: polys.contains(Point(row.lon, row.lat)), axis=1)]
```

The problem is that I don't want to get only the points within **a single polygon** (which the code above does) but **all the points** and know **what polygons** they are in.

Comment: Use `geopandas.sjoin`. That is exactly what you are looking for and it is optimised for large datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for, and it goes something like this:

```
points_inside = gpd.sjoin(gdf, polys[['Name', 'geometry']], op='within')
```